# Missing "Upgrade my library" link in iTunes

Tags: itunes

I would like to upgrade some of the music I purchased on iTunes a few years ago to be DRM free.

I'm even prepared to do this the legal way, but when I go to the app store there is no link in the Quick Links to Upgrade my library.

Also none of the music is listed in my "Purchased" folder even when I am correctly logged in.

Anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: how long a time frame?  are you sure the account you're currently logged into is the same used to purchase the music "way back when"?

Comment: Yes I checked the files themselves and it has the same login id on the summary page of the purchased files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it suddenly occured to me that I bought all the protected music when I lived in the UK three years ago.

I switched my account back to UK billing address and now I see the music available.

Answer (score 0):

When I log in, on the right side of the itms, it says itunes plus. This is where you upgrade.

Comment: Yeah I don't have that.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  So, I contacted Apple tech support and they told me that only a few artists allow DRM free songs on iTunes.  So, when you do purchase a song that is DRM free, you will see the "Upgrade My Library" link in iTunes.